# Chrome blinking triangle

Tags: google-chrome

Using chrome 22.0.1201.0 dev-m version. Got some bug:

[image]

It can appear absolutely on any page. And it's blinking fastly. What can be issue? Do anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like classic screen tearing. Try enabling vertical sync in your video driver's control panel.

An example for AMD is:

[image: AMD Catalyst Control Center Vertical Sync setting]

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with tearing; this is a known bug. Most people get either a [white rectangle](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+white+rectangle) or a [black tab](https://www.google.com/search?q=black+tab+chrome), but the triangle might be a new manifestation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to update your graphics and audio drivers (and chipset as well)

Comment: lol:)) What it has to do with drivers? Yeah my drivers are up to date.

Comment: It has very much to do with drivers as Chrome may use OpenGL and hardware acceleration.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS, Chrome hasn't *suddenly* started using OpenGL and acceleration; it has used them for a long time. If it worked last week, then what could they have changed to make it stop? If they decided to use some fancy, experimental feature, then it is incumbent on the dozen Chrome devs to fix their software, not millions of users to update their drivers (assuming that they even can).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the 22.xx version of Chrome.  I downgraded to the 21.xx beta channel and the tearing has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem still on v22.0.1221.0 dev-m. This definitely is some issue with HW acceleration.
The temporary fix I found until this gets fixed is to disable HW acceleration by going to chrome://flags and switching it off there.

Answer (score 0):

I had that some time back with chrome canary. Problem fixed itself with an update, so its something thats upstream, and eventually got fixed. Upgrading it to the next version seems to fix it.

I do note that its not due to the video card - i've had the same issue with an intel HD graphics/windows 7 system.