# What causes a page to render as if its torn in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome blinking triangle](https://superuser.com/questions/449552/chrome-blinking-triangle)

I've been getting pages that look like they have a tear in them a lot lately and am wondering if anyone else has seen/had/fixed this problem?

[image: torn page]

It doesn't happen to all pages but I'm not sure what the commonality is yet.

Comment: GPU problem? Try updating DirectX and your VGA drivers. Type: chrome://gpu into URL bar to see if it's on or anything.

Comment: By "if it's on or anything" do you mean hardware acceleration.  If so, then yes it's on.  All of the Graphics Feature Status are set to Hardware Accelerated.  DirectX and Nvidia drivers are fully up to date.